# Upgrade R version from 3.2.2 to 3.3.3

Tags: r, linux

I currently have R-3.2.2 version installed on my linux server. Is there a way to use yum install command to upgrade the R version to R-3.3.3 version only.

When i do yum install R i see that the latest version which is 3.4.1 is installed. But i want to install only R-3.3.3 version.

```
yum --showduplicates list r | expand
*Note* Red Hat Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access RHN repositories.
Loaded plugins: aliases, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin,
              : security, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
Installed Packages
R.x86_64                     3.3.3-1.el6                     @epel
Available Packages
R.x86_64                     3.2.3-4.el6                     HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21
R.x86_64                     3.2.3-4.el6                     HDP-UTILS-2.5.0.0
R.x86_64                     3.2.3-4.el6                     HDP-UTILS-2.6.0.3
R.x86_64                     3.2.3-4.el6                     HDP-UTILS-2.6.0.3-8
R.x86_64                     3.4.1-1.el6                     epel

--------------------------------------------
sudo yum install R-3.3.3-1
Loaded plugins: aliases, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package R-3.3.3-1 available.
Error: Nothing to do


sudo yum install r-3.3.3-1.el6
Loaded plugins: aliases, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package r-3.3.3-1.el6 available.
  * Maybe you meant: R
Error: Nothing to do
sudo yum install R-3.3.3-1.el6
Loaded plugins: aliases, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
```

Comment: What's the repository address in your sources list? Does it have 3.4 on it? Change it to 3, uninstall R, do apt-get update, then reinstall. That should work

Comment: Where should i be looking for the repository address?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list See if the repository address has '3.4' next to it

Comment: My OS is linux. I guess /etc/apt/sources.list is related to ubuntu.

Comment: What exactly is your distribution? Linux is a whole family of OS, Ubuntu is one of them. That location would work for Ubuntu, Debian and Mint, which are the distributions I know. Might not work for something like CentOS, RedHat, etc

Comment: This is my distribution:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: /etc/yum.repos.d/ ?

Answer (score 0):

**update**

Your package list says `R.x86_64 3.3.3-1.el6` is installed version. Are you sure it's not?

You can check version with `R --version` from command line or `R.version.string` from within R. If it's not 3.3.3, I'd suggest trying `sudo yum remove r` and re-installing desired version `sudo yum install r-3.3.3-1.el6`

**end of uptate**

You should first find out exact version name and then install it as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x). Something like this:

```
$ yum --showduplicates list r | expand
```

will give you exact naming of versions available from your repo and they install it as (replace 3.3.3 with the version you find in the list)

```
$ sudo yum install r-3.3.3
```

Comment: I have added the output of yum --showduplicates command. But i am not able to install the 3.3.3 version.

Comment: No even sudo yum install r-3.3.3-1.el6 did not work.

Comment: @bigdata, your package list says R.x86_64 3.3.3-1.el6 is installed version. Are you sure it's not? What does R --version says or R.version.string from within R?